# Ограничение Foreach через if - оптимально?

Tags: php, foreach, if

Использование if, это оптимальное решение при ограничении вывода Foreach?

```
foreach ( $xml->Item as $Item )  
 { 

    echo "<td width='185'><img src='".$Item->Picture."' height='220'></td>";
    $i++;
    if($i == 4) break;

 }
```

Comment: Вместо двух строк `$i++; if($i == 4) break;` используйте одну `if(++$i == 4) break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем оно вас смущает или не устраивает? И что значит "оптимальное"? На мой взгляд нормальное решение, в т.ч. потому что оно не ломается если `Item`-ов меньше четырёх (полагаю `$i` изналально равно 0), что позволяет избежать дополнительных проверок (по сравнению с `for`). Но в целом - дело вкуса.

Comment: Петр, вы еще в Новосибе? http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25604415#25604415